# Android night mode crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-dark-theme

I'm trying to use the night mode in my app.
If I change the system setting to "Apps in dark mode > ON", the app is running very well.

If I try to change to dark mode trough my app setting, the app crashed.
Since the dark mode setting is not working, I'm looking at the problem.

I found that the problem is when I try to load the dark mode in the MainActivity:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES); //For night mode theme
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in activity_main: Binary XML file line #11 in content_main: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in content_main: Error inflating class fragment
```

activity_main > Line 15

```
 <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

app_bar_main

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/mytheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/mytheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:backgroundTint="#FBC02D"
        app:rippleColor="#fff"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_24" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Error on line #11 in content_main

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```